# SIP VoIP calling in blackberry

Tags: sip, voip

Is there any open source library or API's for SIP VoIP calling in blackberry.

How to develop a application for VoIP calling.

If it is possible in blackberry than kindly provide me best direction for doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PJSIP](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Download-Source).
PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia stack written in C and it supports audio, video, presence and instant messaging capabilities.

You can refers other links also as [link1](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/07/voip-development-on-blackberry-10/) [link2](http://blog.truphone.com/2012/04/the-blackberry-jam-in-our-donut.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use taki sip softphone for blackberry 10.
http://taki.sourceforge.net/documentation/comment-page-1/#comment-1123